# NetSuite Workflow - Set Field Mandatory Option

Tags: netsuite

I am creating a NetSuite workflow to set a field mandatory. Use case as follows:

If custom field "Customer Has Billing Issue" checkbox is checked, then make "Billing Issue Ticket Number" (custom field) mandatory.

Settings as follows:

```
Workflow:
Name: (any)
Record Type: Customer
Sub Types: Customer
Execute as admin: checked
Status: Released (in Sandbox)
Event definition: On create, on view or update
Trigger type (I've tried all): Current set to Before Record Load

State:
Action 1: Set field Mandatory:
Condition: Company has billing issue = T
Trigger on (I've tried them all) currently on: After field edit
Triggering Client fields: Customer has billing issue
Parameters: Field: Billing Issue Ticket Number 
Mandatory = Checked

Action 2: Set field Mandatory:
Condition: Company has billing issue = F
Trigger on (I've tried them all) currently on: After field edit
Triggering Client fields: Customer has billing issue
Parameters: Field: Billing Issue Ticket Number 
Mandatory = Unchecked
```

I tried all combinations. The workflow is triggering but I cant seem to make the field mandatory. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work like this. Actions have the "Customer Has Billing Issue" field as the triggering field
[image]

Comment: BASIC INFO
Rec Type: Customer
Sub Type: Customer
Exe as Admin = T
Rel Status = Released
INIT
Event Based
EVENT DEF
On Create = T
On View or update = T
Trigger Type = Before Record Load
STATE
Action 1
Set Field Mandatory
BASIC INFO
Trigger on = After Field Edit
Trigger Client Fields = Cust Has Billing Issue
Cond: Customer Has Billing Issue = T
Field = Billing Issue
Mandatory = T
Action 2
Set Field Mandatory
BASIC INFO
Trigger on = After Field Edit
Trigger Client Fields = Cust Has Billing Issue
Cond: Cust Has Billing Issue = F
Field = Billing Issue
Mandatory = F

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had the same question. II also made sure to have Triggering client fields set to the correct field.